# unable to access the google app engine application/ gets deployed on incorrect project id

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine, gcloud, gae-eclipse-plugin

My web application on google app engine was built using jdk 1.7 and eclipse. The project worked fine on the localhost server and so i deployed to the cloud using eclipse tool. The issue is that the application instead of being deployed to [my_app_id].appspot.com gets deployed at 1-dot-[my_app_id].appspot.com

Now i can access the application on 1-dot-[my_app_id].appspot.com but thats not the pid i wish to have.I have double checked the project id and i haven't added any 1-dot before my app id. My actual [my_app_id].appspot.com displays just a Hello World page, which is not getting updated  even on using mvn appengine:update.

Please suggest if i have made any mistake while deployment.

Comment: In the developer console, on the versions page, you should see the deployed versions.  I suspect your version 1 is not the default one, if so just make it default (or switch traffic to it).

Comment: potentially interesting https://cloudplatform.googleblog.com/2017/01/expanding-our-IDE-support-with-a-new-Eclipse-plugin-for-App-Engine.html

Comment: @DanCornilescu  Thanks a lot !!! the fix worked

Answer (score 2):

The behavior you mention suggests that your app version 1 was correctly deployed, but it's not the default version (see [Routing via URL](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/how-requests-are-routed#routing_via_url)).

In the Google Cloud Platform console, on the [versions page](https://console.cloud.google.com/appengine/versions), you should see the deployed versions. Just make the version 1 the default one (or switch traffic to it).

By default when deploying using the gcloud SDK the new version becomes the default one (but that can be changed). For example, from [gcloud app deploy](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/app/deploy):

> `--promote`
>
> Promote the deployed version to receive all traffic. True by default.
>   To change the default behavior for your current environment, run:
>
> `$ gcloud config set app/promote_by_default false`
>
> Overrides the default `promote_by_default` property value for this
>   command invocation. Use `--no-promote` to disable.

But I'm not familiar with Eclipse, I don't know if/how its GAE plugin can be configured to automatically make the deployed version the default one.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the [Google Cloud Tools for Eclipse plugin](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-eclipse/) then in the deploy dialog you can set the deployed version to be served from the `[my_app_id].appspot.com` URL by selecting the checkbox `Promote the deployed version to receive all traffic`:

[image: Promote deployed version setting]